# Please help me with a calculation using Taylor's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, statistics, taylor-expansion

## Qustion

Suppose the following holds:
$$
\mathbb E[e^X] = e^\theta \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^k}\cdot\frac{1}{2^k k!}.
$$

Then, We want to show
$$
\mathbb E[e^X - e^\theta] = \frac{e^\theta}{2n} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2} \right).
$$

Please give me a road map to show this.

## What I know

・The RHS of the assumed equation is a power series in $1/n$.

・According to the reference, it seems to be shown using Taylor's theorem.

・I know Taylor's theorem, but I don't know where to apply it in this case.

Comment: $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^k}\cdot\frac{1}{2^k k!}=O(\frac 1 {n^{2}})$

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you!!!